# Delete all columns in a list

Tags: sharepoint-online

In a SharePoint list how can I delete all the columns in that list rather than deleting them one by one?

I went to the list setting, but I could not find the option to delete the columns.

List settings:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to delete all columns at the same time via the user interface, additionally it's not possible to delete all columns (the Title column and Created columns cannot be deleted for example).

You could use either the Microsoft Graph API or SharePoint APIs to delete columns programmatically.

Comment: Is `PowerShell` used for such programming? Also, can you recommend any such APIs? You can expand on this in your answer, thank you.